# Function returns cells value not cells location - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to setup a function for Regex which returns a `cell.address`. It's 99% working except it seems to return the value of the cell `test` vs the cell location and I can't figure it out.

Debugging:

It says `Object variable or with block variable not set` if I `Dim celladdr As Range`

but if I comment that out, then the error changes to `Object doesn't support this property or method` and I can see that `celladdr = test`.

I then tried `Set celladdr = Range(celladdr.Address)` and get `Object Required`.

Can anybody point out the error?

Here is some stripped down code:
Note, I hardcoded the RegEx pattern as that function works as expected, the problem seems to be in the `RegExSearch` function, but I can add more code back in if needed.

```
Public Sub TESTING()
  Dim celladdr As Range
  celladdr = RegExFunc("TEST")
  ActiveSheet.celladdr.Select
End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegExFunc(var) As Variant
  RegExSearchPattern = RegExPattern(var)
  RegExFunc = RegExSearch(RegExSearchPattern)
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegExPattern(my_string) As Variant
  RegExPattern = "([a-z]{4})"
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegExSearch(strPattern) As Range
    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strInput As String

    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set rng = Range("A1:Z255")

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells

        If rcell <> "" Then

            If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = rcell.Value

            With regexp
                .Global = False
                .MultiLine = False
                .ignoreCase = True
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regexp.Test(strInput) Then
                MsgBox rcell & " Matched in Cell" & rcell.Address
                Set RegExSearch = Range(rcell.Address)
                MsgBox RegExSearch
            End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were various instances in which you needed to `Set` the object and one in which a `Dim` was needed. Since you declared almost everything a Variant, it makes it a bit harder to pinpoint the breakdown. It's best, in my experience to always specifically declare the variables in VBA.

I ran the following adjusted code (added a few sets as noted above) and it worked without any decompile or run time errors.

```
Public Sub TESTING()
  Dim celladdr As Range
  Set celladdr = RegExFunc("TEST")
  celladdr.Select
End Sub

Public Function RegExFunc(var As String) As Range
Dim RegExSearchPattern As String
  RegExSearchPattern = RegExPattern(var)
  Set RegExFunc = RegExSearch(RegExSearchPattern)
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegExPattern(my_string As String) As String
  RegExPattern = "([a-z]{4})"
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegExSearch(strPattern As String) As Range
    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strInput As String

    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set rng = Range("A1:Z255")

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells

        If rcell <> "" Then

            If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = rcell.Value

            With regexp
                .Global = False
                .MultiLine = False
                .ignoreCase = True
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regexp.Test(strInput) Then
                MsgBox rcell & " Matched in Cell" & rcell.Address
                Set RegExSearch = Range(rcell.Address)
                MsgBox RegExSearch
            End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I still get the `Object doesn't support this property or method` when running. I suspect you didn't type a 4 lettered word in any cell in the range, to test it needs to find a result. I understand I need to start declaring things as what they are more specifically to help avoid this in the future.

Comment: I just tried your edit and it worked! Im about to head home, i'll have to read deeper tomorrow, but thank you this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Indeed. I also adjusted the line to not be `ActiveSheet` but only the range returned.

Answer (score 1):

A cell address is just a string; you don't Set it, simply assign it with `=`.

```
RegExSearch = rcell.Address
```

... will return the absolute cell address.

You might want to consider exiting the `For Each rcell In rng.Cells` loop if the pattern is found. There doesn't seem to be any point in continuing unless you want the cell addresses of the union of all matching cells.

```
        If regexp.Test(strInput) Then
            MsgBox rcell & " Matched in Cell" & rcell.Address
            RegExSearch = rcell.Address
            MsgBox RegExSearch
            Exit For
        End If
```

You're setting identical RegEx arguments inside the loop. Move the argument assignment above the `For Each rcell In rng.Cells` loop.

```
    With regexp
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .ignoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
```

Comment: That gives me an error on that line `Object variable or With block variable not set`. I tried that before as well, but then it errored on that line. I had it `Exit Function` inside the `If Regex Test` statement, but I'll adjust that after it's working. I'm not sure if I want to stop on 1st or last result.

Comment: Declare the function properly. `Public Function RegExSearch(strPattern) As String` or `Public Function RegExSearch(strPattern)` (the last one is a variant so it can return either a value or an address).

Comment: @user11343412 Excellent point about the range not being added to each other. I thought the same but didn't address it in my answer. +1 for that.